# Intent created by fragment does not trigger onNewIntent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent

I am developing an app which uses an sdk that makes use of intents to communicate between the sdk and my code.
In my app, whenever a user scans a barcode, the active fragment sends a broadcast containing a scan intent. The MainActivity class decodes this intent and via a shared viewmodel, sends it back to the fragment.

I'm currently facing the problem that my onNewIntent is never called. I tried handling it manually using a custom function but this does not seem like the right approach (and it doesn't seem to work either).
I guess either something is wrong with my intent, or my viewmodel isn't working well, or possibly a combination of both.

```kotlin
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    private val intentViewModel by activityViewModels<IntentViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        val btnScanner = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnScan)

        //If usercredentials get a value, that means the user has succesfully authenticated
        intentViewModel.userCredentials.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { credentials ->
            if (credentials[0] != "" && credentials[1] != "") {
             
                navigateToHome(intentViewModel.userCredentials.value!!)
            }
        })

        //Intent set by activity
        intentViewModel.intent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { intent ->
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
            val decodedData =
                intent!!.getStringExtra(
                    resources.getString(R.string.datawedge_intent_key_data)
                )
            //Never gets called --> intent never gets registered by activity
            Timber.d("Intent observer got called with value $decodedData")
            getUserCredentials(decodedData!!)
        })

        //Creates an intent based on motionevent, which gets broadcasted
        btnScanner.setOnTouchListener { v, motionEvent ->
            decodeEvent(v, motionEvent)
        }
        return view
    }
    
    //Hardcoded authentication example
    private fun getUserCredentials(badgeId: String) {
        var creds = Array(2) { "" }
        creds[0] = "12345678"
        creds[1] = "Logistics"
        intentViewModel.userCredentials.value = creds
    }

    private fun decodeEvent(v: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //  Button pressed, start scan
            val dwIntent = Intent()
            dwIntent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
            dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SOFT_SCAN_TRIGGER", "START_SCANNING")
            dwIntent.putExtra("Type", "START")
            activity?.sendBroadcast(dwIntent)
            //(activity as MainActivity).handleIntent(dwIntent)
        } else if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //  Button released, end scan
            val dwIntent = Intent()
            dwIntent.action = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
            dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SOFT_SCAN_TRIGGER", "STOP_SCANNING")
            dwIntent.putExtra("Type", "END")
            activity?.sendBroadcast(dwIntent)
            //  (activity as MainActivity).handleIntent(dwIntent)
        }
        return true
    }

    fun navigateToHome(userCredentials: Array<String>) {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireView())
            .navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeFragment(userCredentials))
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private val  intentViewModel by viewModels<IntentViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate( savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

   //User scanned a barcode, which created an intent in the fragment
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        intentViewModel.intent.value = intent
    }

}
```

```kotlin
class IntentViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var intent = MutableLiveData<Intent?>()
    var userCredentials = MutableLiveData<Array<String>>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnNewIntent` will invoke if you specified your activity in the manifest with launch mode to "singleTop"

Comment: I already have `android:launchMode="singleTop"`in my manifest but this does not solve it.